# Sniffing SSL packets using Wireshark

Tags: android, ssl, wireshark, packet-sniffers, man-in-the-middle

I'd like to reverse engineer a decoder. So I am using an android application to control the decoder and I want to sniff the flow of packets that the application emits to the decoder.

The packets are sent over SSL so they are all encrypted. Apart from Wireshark, I tried using mitmproxy and mitmdump but in vain.

Knowing that it is impossible for me to get the private key from my decoder, I am looking for a way to use a proxy (basically man in the middle) that will enable me to generate a new certificate so I can use its private key on Wireshark (instead of the one of my decoder) to decrypt my packets.

Is there any way I can do this? I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/).

It allows you to send a fake certificate and to intercept SSL traffic.

It won't work if the android application is using certificate pining, though.

Comment: Thank you @blue112 ! I'm going to try it.

Comment: the documentation says that I Wireshark will only intercept http and https traffic, but I want TCP packets too.

Comment: @yosra Wireshark is perfectly able to display tcp and udp packets as well

Comment: If you use Charles Proxy, you don't need to use Wireshark

Comment: @yosra It is just the other way around: AFAIK Charles proxy only works with http/https. Wireshark supports all protocols, however the SSL/TLS decryption requires to have the server private key and the use of a cipher that does not use perfect forward secrecy.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your comment. But what if I use a proxy between the server and my phone, the proxy will intercept the message that my phone is sending/receiving, and then I decrypt those messages using the private key of my proxy? This is the approach I am trying to develop, but I don't know if that'spossible or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid changing the certificate (which won't work with many applications), you could try injecting code into the Android app to sniff and dump SSL traffic. Take a look at https://github.com/5alt/ssl_logger (5alt's fork works with Android). Note that **you need root for this**.

This works by hooking functions inside OpenSSL so that the raw traffic can be dumped before encryption/after decryption.

You have to install Frida Android server: https://www.frida.re/docs/android/

- Connect phone with USB debugging on
- Download `frida-server` for the right CPU architecture from  https://github.com/frida/frida/releases

  - To know which CPU architecture your device is using (for getting the right download), you can run `getprop ro.product.cpu.abi` on the phone.
- Push to `/data/local/tmp` of Android (as root), make executable (`chmod 755`).
- Run `/data/local/tmp/frida-server` on the phone.
- On your computer, install `frida-tools` using `pip install --user frida-tools`. (Must be Python2, not Python3!)
- List processes to see if everything works, by running `frida-ps -U` on your computer with the phone connected
- Forward Frida's ports: `adb forward tcp:27042 tcp:27042; adb forward tcp:27043 tcp:27043`
- Get [`ssl_logger`](https://github.com/5alt/ssl_logger) on your computer
- Run `python ssl_logger.py -pcap log.pcap -remote com.android.package.name` on your computer. (Note that `-remote` is not explained in the readme, but it's necessary!.)

  - You can add `-verbose` to see live traffic output.
  - Let it run until you are done, quit with Ctrl+C. You then have a file `log.pcap` which you can analyze in Wireshark.
  - Note: In case you are getting a JavaScript error, you have to edit `ssl_logger.py` and insert a line with `var addresses, SSL_get_fd, SSL_get_session, SSL_SESSION_get_id, getpeername, getsockname;` before the line with `function initializeGlobals`.

Tutorials for using Frida on Android:  https://11x256.github.io/